# Cross origin error from local disk to local disk (basic HTML only, not AJAX)

Tags: html

I have `test.html` and `test.svg`, **on my local disk**, the first references the second:

```
<img src="test.svg" . . . 

<div style='-webkit-mask-image: url(test.svg) . . .
```

When I load the page the `<img>` part loads, the `<div>` part does not, and I get the following error:

```
Access to image at 'file:///C:/Users/Cz/Desktop/test/test.svg' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, https, chrome-untrusted.
```

A couple of things confuse me here:

- the HTML page is on my local disk, so requesting access to another (adjacent) local file shouldn't be a CORS problem.
- even if it is detected as an issue, the `<img>` part still works, which contradicts the above error.

So in essence, how can I load one file on disk from another? Preferably without having to set up a server!

Answer (score 0):

> the HTML page is on my local disk, so requesting access to another (adjacent) local file shouldn't be a CORS problem.

Yes, it should. This is by design.

Imagine if someone sent you an HTML document as an email attachment. You double click it, your email client saves it to a temporary location and opens it in your web browser. It is now on the same origin as everything else on your disk.

---

> even if it is detected as an issue, the `<img>` part still works, which contradicts the above error.

The error doesn't relate to the `<img>`. It relates to the `-webkit-mask-image`.